# How can I set a form to have a transparent background in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to set my form's background to transparent but faced an error "property value is not valid". I don't know if there is a simple way to set a transparent background image as a form in windows?

I'm trying to make a c# windows form application.

I cannot upload a picture yet.For example I want to run my app and see a picture of a book (that doesn't have any white background borders)including tools

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please *post your code* and improve your tags so that we know whether you are using WinForms or WPF.

Comment: If the OP said "form", then I guess it's safe to assume WinForms, no?

Comment: @Douglas: Or ASP.Net Web Forms, right?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Possibly, but unlikely given that they're asking about making it transparent.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387680/transparent-background-on-winforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a code that may help you achieve what you are trying to do. The following code will make the form transparent but leave the controls visible. **If you want to hide the controls as well, I suggest you set the form opacity to 0%**

```
this.BackColor = Color.White;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.White;
```

Thanks,

I hope this helps :)

Comment: But I can't use this code for other background colors.Do you have any Idea?

Comment: @mdhr Why not? Please let me know what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Kinected Thanks! Glad you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using Windows Forms then set the opacity to any value from 0.0 to 1.0. Having 0.0 (complete transparency) and 1.0 (complete opacity).

```
form.Opacity = 0.0;
```

MSDN Source: [How to create a transparent form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czke9azk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).