# how can i make semi-transparent form? (delphi)

Tags: delphi, transparency

I need to make semi-transparent Form like a terminal in linux systems.
For example (transparency):
[image: http://hamzaed.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Screenshot-16.png]

You see?
- Window = x% transparency
- the font (subtitles) = 0%

I tried to use Alpha-Blend (Form1) but its works for a whole window with all components, fonts etc, but i dont want a transparent font! I want the same effect as the terminal in linux (font visibility 100%). How can i do this?

btw. forgive me for my poor english and thanks for the help

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309770/c-sharp-transparent-background-for-window-form

Comment: Does your form have the GlassFrame property?

Comment: im using XE5 delphi and win7

Comment: You won't be able to use standard controls, but there are lot of answers adressing your search : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+UpdateLayeredWindow

Comment: as an Delphi XE5 user you can use *FireMonkey* framework to achieve such effect, just set form `Fill.Color` to `#88FFFFFF` and `transparency=true`

Comment: That looks like a classic victory for form over function.