# WinForm transparent image issue

Tags: c#, windows, image, winforms, png

I have a WinForm and I set a transparent PNG image for the label. In Windows XP, the transparency displays properly, but in Windows 7, the white text (as seen in the example URL below) becomes transparent (it should be solid white). I'm also wondering if there is a way to smooth the edges of the transparent image so it isn't as choppy.

```
label1.Image = global::WinProgram.Properties.Resources.image_name;
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Due to your limited code, I'd be guessing on this one but i find this very likely to be your problem. In WinForms there is a so called TransparencyKey, I'm guessing that you sett'd the SolidWhite as your TransparencyKey.

You can refer to this post: [Transparent Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387680/transparent-background-on-winforms)