# C# proper image alpha layer when form is invisible

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, alpha

I'm looking for a way to have images on invisible form that allow alpha transparency and allow to place and use buttons/labels etc.

I've tried this [Transparent background on winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387680/transparent-background-on-winforms), layered window and many more, nothing fully successful. I've ended up with such failures https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uIF6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Transparency key only makes one color transparent, which doesn't work on images that have smooth color gradients on the edges.

First of all, are you certain that your image has a transparent background?

Layered window is exactly what you should use to achieve the desired effect. Since you don't give much details, I don't know what's wrong with your implementation. Try to use the `PerPixelAlphaForm` from the following article: [Per Pixel Alpha Blend in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1822/Per-Pixel-Alpha-Blend-in-C). When used correctly, it will work (even though the article is really old).

Comment: I've used Layered window and the image worked fine, but the problem is that in layered window you cannot add buttons/labels etc, only the image will be drew (its good for starting screens and such, but I need fully functional program). Thanks for that article tho, I'll try to do as it says.

Comment: I've created additional form that's layered window and now I dont know what to do. http://i.imgur.com/Q231QPX.png Two forms complex into one application, will this work? how?