# Creating a floating always-on top-button for windows (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, button

I'd like to create a column with floating buttons that act as an overlay during normal activities in Windows. The buttons would always be on top of the working windows of the user (excel, browser, no full screen applications) and would simply be clickable to start and stop timers.

Is there any way to code this (preferably in C#) without any ugly borders/windows. Ideally, I would like it to look like the floating [Dropbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqhKR.png) icon or the Facebook notifications on Android. It would only have to work on Windows.

Comment: You can just [create a transparent form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387680/transparent-background-on-winforms) with `FormBorderStyle = None` and `TopMost = true` and then put your buttons above it, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would need to do:

- Create your form with buttons
- Make the form (not the buttons) transparent and have no borders
- Make the form stay the topmost window at all times
- Probably handle moving the buttons by dragging them, since the controls on the forms border that normally do this are gone now

You should be able to do all of this using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf).

So see how far you get with your current knowledge of WPF and then read a good book or tutorial on what's missing. Feel free to ask a question once you get stuck. Don't forget to include your code then.