# Slow label background update when scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, transparency, flowlayoutpanel

I am currently facing the following problem:

I have a Windows Form with a BackgroundImage. On top of this is a FlowLayoutPanel with a half transparent BackColor (`Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Black)` to be more precise). On this FlowLayoutPanel, i have multiple labels one below the other with `BackColor = Color.Transparent`. Everything works fine until I scroll on the FLP to see labels that are further down. When doing this, you can clearly see how each label is updating their Background to match the Image on the form. Is there an option to increase this render performance? If not, then i have to choose a solid background color for the panel, which would not be as pretty... The labels and the flowlayoutpanel are custom controls with Double Buffer enabled.

[image]

Comment: I haven't worked with transparency but as i read somewhere winform's transparency is not transparency but control is getting image behind it and representing it as it's background. What could you try is advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387680/transparent-background-on-winforms) answer but it is just try out. Again i haven't worked with transparency that much and do not know but why not try :)

Comment: @AleksaRistic `TransparencyKey` is a property of `Form` and I have not figured out how to use it on a control unfortunately.

Comment: Well i do not know what to tell you then. Only thing i know is transparency IS transparency (with alpha) in WPF and that is reason why it is used if you want to create more friendly UI applications.