# How to make it so when you drag the form it turns transparent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I am trying to make it so when you drag, or hold your cursor on the dragable part of the form, the form will turn transparent, like 80% transparent.

Comment: OK. Let us know when you encounter a specific issue with that. It's not for us to teach you how or to do it for you. You need to do the research and make your best attempt, then ask us for help with a specific issue if and when it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387680/transparent-background-on-winforms)?

Comment: You could change the Form.Opacity to 80